# How to access a UFS2 formatted drive in OSX/High Sierra?

Tags: mount, osx, ufs

I found this [guide](https://wiki.gutzmann.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6651931) and I was able to successfully compile the ufs executable.

I already have OSXFUSE because I needed it earlier for accessing ext4 partitions.

I was able to successfully run the ufs command using:

```
./ufs --dmg /dev/disk7s1 --type ufs /Users/myuser/Documents/my-mount-point
```

If I run:

```
df -h
```

the UFS2 partition shows up and the total size, used space and remaining space are correctly identified. **My problem is that I cannot see any of the files.**

Running:

```
ls /Users/myuser/Documents/my-mount-point
```

gives me:

```
ls: /Users/myuser/Documents/my-mount-point: no such file or directory
```

**Any ideas how this can be done using free/opensource tools?**

Thanks